# Pandas: Preferred order of methods on a part of a table

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have started learning Pandas module ny "[Data School](https://www.youtube.com/user/dataschool)" Q&A series and in his ["How do I handle missing values in pandas?"](https://youtu.be/fCMrO_VzeL8?list=PL5-da3qGB5ICCsgW1MxlZ0Hq8LL5U3u9y) video he wrote the following line of code:

```
ufo.isna().tail()
```

If I am not wrong, the following line would be more efficient:

```
ufo.tail().isna()
```

My question is not only in this case, but in general, is the order of methods on a part of a table matters? And if so then when exactly?

Comment: Yes, the order matters, if that is what you are asking. Python does not (and really can't in principle) do any optimizations that would make it see that `tail` should come first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my opinion, here should be used logic:

```
first filter for reduce number of rows and then apply some method only for filtered data
```

not like:

```
first apply method for all data and then filter
```

So for better performance is use first one - filter and apply method - here are tested missing values onle for first 5 rows:

```
ufo.tail().isna()
```

But here are tested all values and then filtered first 5 tows, so if 10M rows performance is much worse:

```
ufo.isna().tail()
```